# Resources for Learning 508 Compliance/Accessibility Requirements for GIS Figures

Tags: cartography, arcgis-10.2, maps, accessibility

Does anyone know of any quality resources (books, papers, presentations, websites) for learning about [508 Compliance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_508_Amendment_to_the_Rehabilitation_Act_of_1973)/Accessibility requirements in relation to cartography (GIS figures and templates)? This is also in relation to colorblindness and visually-impaired end users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One presumes you are already familiar with [Section508.gov](http://www.section508.gov/) but those who may find this later may not be.

For general accessibility resources see [The Accessibility Project](http://a11yproject.com/) although that is primarily focused on web accessibility.

For more cartographic specific accessibility tests consider the [Colour Contrast Analyser](http://www.paciellogroup.com/resources/contrastanalyser/) and [Vischeck](http://www.vischeck.com/vischeck/).

Answer (score 1):

colorbrewer will address colorblindness:
http://colorbrewer2.org/
for web based, best bet is too follow w3c standards:
http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/
for native, you should reference the operators site, for example, i know ios a11y information is up on apple's site, and the same for microsoft

Answer (score 0):

For those of you that may still be following this, I finally found some additional documentation on Section 508 Compliance that comes from the Centers for Medicare and Medicaid Services. I would say this is a good follow-up to the above post from @jwd630.

[Making Documents Section 508 Compliant](http://www.cms.gov/Research-Statistics-Data-and-Systems/CMS-Information-Technology/Section508/508-Compliant-doc.html)